# Travelling around the world

Tags: riddle, geography

Μy destination is a part of the world. Part of the destination, when read backwards, is a living thing, and another part of the destination, scrambled, is a delicious meal. **What part of the world is my destination?**

HINT:

> The part of the world is not in Europe, Asia, Africa or Australia.

HINT:

> The living thing is a variety of an apple tree.

Comment: There are many solutions i think u shld add more specification

Comment: @AakashMathur I'm not sure if this is true, as none of the current answers fully match the question; I think it's a stretch to consider "tea" a meal, and "man" from Manchester isn't read backwards, as specified by the question

Comment: The clues are too broad. there are millions of places, and thousands of living things with short enough names that they can be found, reversed or otherwise, as a part of them. scrambling a part of a word gives, again, very many options, and a"delicious meal" again could be anything edible. Going at this with a word list, I would expect at least a hundred possible answers, so additional constraints are necessary.

Comment: @samm [Tea](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_(meal)) is one of the better choices for a meal that is more delicious than other meals.

Comment: Hello @Vassilis Parassidis. V guvax V xabj gur nafjre. Va beqre gb znxr vg zber fcrpvsvp lbh pna nqq: Gurer vf nyfb n urnirayl bowrpg va gung cynpr. Nz V evtug?

Answer (score 4):

This could be:

> The Indian state of **[UTTAR PRADESH](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uttar_Pradesh)**. Home to 200 million people and the Taj Mahal, it is the largest state in India and a popular destination for tourists, making it an appropriate target for a puzzle like this.

The 'living thing' concealed backwards here is a:

> **RAT** - UT**TAR** PRADESH.

The 'delicious meal' scrambled in another part of the name is:

> **SPREAD** - UTTAR **PRADES**H (where 'spread' means 'a large and impressively elaborate meal').

Comment: I think it would be hard to do much better than this as the two parts are separate and there are very few unused letters. +1

Comment: V guvax gur nafjre vf n 2 jbeq pbhagel anzr va Prageny Nzrevpn jvgu gur fnzr yvivat guvat sebz lbhe nafjre ohg gur svefg jbeq nantenzf gb terng zrny!

Comment: @DrD rot13(Vs lbh zrna PBFGN EVPN, V jbhyq or vapyvarq gb ehyr vg bhg fvapr ENG naq EBNFG bireync, zrnavat gur frpbaq vfa'g grpuavpnyyl 'nabgure cneg' bs gur anzr. Be unir V zvffrq nabgure fhofgevat urer? Rvgure jnl, V'q or vagrerfgrq gb xabj vs guvf vf jung gur BC'f vagragvba vf...!)

Answer (score 0):

Another Possibility is:

> Egg Harbor Township[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_Harbor_Township,_New_Jersey), which is a township in New Jersey.

The living thing concealed backwards here could be:

> Rob, which is a name of someone who could be living.

Scrambled, it is a delicious meal:

> Egg. When scrambled, eggs become scrambled eggs, which (in my opinion) is a delicious meal.

Answer (score -1):

> the State of Israel

> Part of the destination, when read backwards is a living thing

> rae → ear

> another part of the destination, scrambled, is a delicious meal

> ate → tea

Answer (score -1):

> the State of Qatar

> Part of the destination, when read backwards is a living thing

> tar → rat

> another part of the destination, scrambled, is a delicious meal

> ate → tea